# Marshall/Unmarshall

Tags: c#

Hou should i convert IntPtr to IShellBrowser?

Comment: Have a look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FileDialogs.aspx?msg=3172865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [`Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getobjectforiunknown.aspx) or [`Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gettypedobjectforiunknown.aspx).